# how to add texture to an object import in .stl format

Tags: texturing

Extreme blender newbie here..

Is it possible to import an object in .stl format and add a texture to it?

I seem to be able to do it fine with any object I create inside blender, but when I import an .stl it will not give me the option to do so.

Could anyone please tell me the steps?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

An image or procedural [texture](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/blender_render/textures/introduction.html) is used by a [material](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/blender_render/materials/introduction.html) to control the color over the surface of the object.

Using blender render, a texture can only be added if a material has been [assigned to the object](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/blender_render/materials/material_panel.html). Also note that the [texture panel](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/blender_render/textures/texture_panel.html) has sub-sections, you will want the material textures option to be selected. After importing an .stl file, there may be no material, so first create the material and then add a texture.

[image]

Also there are differences based on the [render engine](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/introduction.html#render-engines) chosen, cycles uses a nodes based system that allows [textures](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/cycles/nodes/types/textures/index.html) to be incorporated at different stages of the material.